# How to make a class available to Spring within Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, module

I'm working with an application which has a modular architecture - each module is contained in a WAR file running on top of Tomcat. One of the modules allows users to extend its functionality with a request `Interceptor` interface, which is `@Autowire`d into the class by Spring.

I'm working on a custom Interceptor and would like to make it available to Spring for autowiring within the module. Until now I've been building a custom version of the module's WAR which contains my interceptor, but I do not feel that this is a clean approach because the idea was to make the application easily extensible, and building my own fork for this reason seems to almost eliminate the benefits of the Interceptor interface.

I know one possibility is to crack the WAR open (it's just a ZIP archive) and drop a custom JAR in there, but that doesn't feel right either. Perhaps there is a way of adding custom JARs using Maven? Is there an industry-standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have at least a partial answer, everyone is welcome to provide a better one.

There is a helpful documentation [page about class loading in Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html). It describes where classes are loaded from, snippets which are most interesting to a casual reader are reproduced below:

*unpacked classes and resources in `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`

JAR files in `$CATALINA_BASE/lib`

unpacked classes and resources in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`

JAR files in `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`*

***WebappX* — A class loader is created for each web application that is deployed in a single Tomcat instance. All unpacked classes and resources in the `/WEB-INF/classes` directory of your web application, plus classes and resources in JAR files under the `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your web application, are made visible to this web application, but not to other ones.**